# My python calculator is returning a string and not the correct sequence of math operations

Tags: python, string, integer

This has been bugging me and I'm sure it's a simply fix, but I can't find an answer.

```
import math

def add():
    return x + y

def subtract():
    return x - y

def multiply():
    return x * y

def divide():
    return x / y


x = input("Enter the first number. ")
y = input("Enter the second number. ")
print("1. Add  2. Subtract  3. Multiply  4. Divide ")

choice = input("Enter your choice of calculation. ").lower()
if choice == "1" or "add":
    print (add())
elif choice == "2" or "subtract":
    print (subtract())
elif choice == "3" or "multiply":
    print (multiply())
elif choice == "4" or "divide":
    print (divide())
else:
    print("That is not a valid choice. ")
```

Example: 2 + 3 = 23 NOT 5
Example: 3 * 3 = 33 NOT 9

Comment: Btw  you dont need to `import math` for this.

Comment: lol ok thanks i didnt know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because all values that `input()` captures are strings. You need to convert the values to numbers, (integers `int()` in this case) before performing your calculations.

```
x = int( input("Enter the first number. ") )
y = int( input("Enter the second number. ") )
```

The reason your code is still working is because many of these operations also work on strings. For example, `+` will concatenate two strings together.

Additionally, your `if` conditional expressions are also written incorrectly. You need to compare the variable to the expected value between each `or` operator.

```
if choice == "1" or choice == "add":
```

The way you had it before, the condition would always evaluate as `True` because a non-empty string evaluates as a "truthy" in Python. Since you're using an `or` condition, only one of the conditions has to be met and the non-empty string condition is always met. Since your addition check was first, it will be the only operation to get called.

```
if choice == "1" or "add": # always True because 'add' is a non-empty string
```

This is the same as saying:

```
if 'add':
```

Comment: This wont work because he's expecting words to be passed to the input, ie divide, multiply.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the if conditions were strings afterwards. Fixed.

Comment: @Kabdmenrs You're welcome, but don't forget to vote and mark one of the answers correct.

Comment: i can't yet i have to wait but real quick. its only adding the numbers now

Comment: whenever i do any operation it just adds them

Comment: I've updated the answer with additional information about your if conditions.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned previously, the problem you are having is due to not converting explicitly between types. This is quite concise if you want a command line calculator:

```
print('Type exit to quit')
while 1:
    entered = input('Enter expression to evaluate: ')
    if entered == 'exit': break
    print(eval(entered))
```

Example output:

```
Type exit to quit
Enter expression to evaluate: 5+5
10
Enter expression to evaluate: 3**2
9
Enter expression to evaluate: 15*(3-1)
30
Enter expression to evaluate: exit
```

To fix yours:

```
import math

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

def divide(x, y):
    return x / y

while 1:
    while 1:
        try:
            x = float(input("Enter the first number. "))
            break
        except:
            print('Not a valid number!')

    while 1:
        try:
            y = float(input("Enter the second number. "))
            break
        except:
            print('Not a valid number!')

    print("\n1. Add  2. Subtract  3. Multiply  4. Divide ")
    choice = input("Enter your choice of calculation. ").lower()
    if choice in ["1","a","add"]:
        print(add(x,y))
    elif choice in ["2","s","subtract"]:
        print(subtract(x,y))
    elif choice in ["3","m","multiply"]:
        print(multiply(x,y))
    elif choice in ["4","d","divide"]:
        print(divide(x,y))
    else:
        print("That is not a valid choice. ")
```

Comment: but this kinda ruins the point of the whole calculator thing. im now having a problem were it only returns addition though

Comment: Edited to include a revised version of your code that typecasts properly and defines arguments for your functions.

Comment: You're over-complicating OP's code. He/she is obviously still learning so you shouldn't complicate your answer more than necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You need to typecast the input numbers from strings to ints so that mathematical operations return the desired output.

```
 x = int(input("Enter the first number. "))
 y = int(input("Enter the second number. "))
```

Comment: While the code is correct, you should really add some explanation as to what this is doing.

Comment: its a calculator for python. mentioned in the title.